# Start a long running job with a web service call

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, architecture, data-transfer

We have a data transfer between 2 systems that can take upto a few hours. The code for doing this transfer is written in C#.

We would like to trigger the transfer with a WCF web service call.

Ideally we would like the web service call to return at once, with a message "OK job started", and then the job to run on the server untill it is complete.

What is the best way to do this?

The possible problems we see are:

- web service timing out before job finished
- job stops after returning result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although not entirely similar to your predicament, I had a similar scenario with my MVC application.  There are lots of "Jobs" to do that involve importing data, batch emails, financial processes etc.

Basically, I created a windows service which had a job manager, and obviously the various jobs that could be done.  It also ran a light HttpServer.  This allowed the main MVC application to talk to the service.  One sends a request to start jobs and get the status of all jobs or a particular job (when a job is started it is given a unique ID).

So if I was going to implement it in your case, I'd add a download job which did the actual work, and instigate it from the MVC App via a JSON call.  The status of the download could be queried at any time by using the ID passed back from the "StartJob" JSON call.  Your main web request is therefore handled and over immediately.

Answer (score 1):

I'd write a console application that does this job and let the Web Service call that application.
Running heavy processes within the web server itself is never a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

You may use  background thread on the WebServce call.